# Does MS PnP Unity Scan for Assemblies Like StructureMap?

Tags: structuremap, unity-container, ioc-container

In [Using StructureMap 2.5 to scan all assemblies in a folder](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2008/10/18/using-structuremap-2-5-to-scan-all-assemblies-in-a-folder.aspx), we can see that StructureMap uses `AssembliesFromPath()` to explicitly look for types to resolve. What is the equivalent of this in Microsoft Unity? Because *Unity* is such a generic term, searching for documents about this online is not that easy.

**Update:** Unity has something called an [Assembly Matching Rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203151.aspx) but its description does not communicate to me that it scans *folders*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Assembly Matching Rule is used for applying interception to classes constructed by Unity and not for container registration.  Unity itself does not have any convention-based scanning functionality like StructureMap.  There is a CodePlex project that adds similar functionality to Unity though.   http://autoregistration.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is changing in Unity 3.0 which will support registration by convention.

Answer (score 1):

Registration by Convention was added in Unity 3.0. Nice examples of this feature are provided in "Developer's Guide to Dependency Injection Using Unity" in solution in samples named OtherUnitySamples. You can find the book here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx)

and code samples here:

[unity.codeplex.com/downloads/get/683531](http://unity.codeplex.com/downloads/get/683531)