# Configure Unity Injection for all descendants of some base class

Tags: inheritance, dependency-injection, unity-container

How to configure Unity so that any class derived from some base class would go through injection pipeline defined for base class.

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public IDependency Dependency {get;set;}
};

public class Derived1: Base
{
};

public class Derived2: Base
{
};


container.RegisterType<Base>(new InjectionProperty("Dependency", new ResolvedParameter<IDependency>()));
var d1 = container.Resolve<Derived1>();
```

Thus, I need to **register base class** with Unity while **resolve derived classes** so that all injections specified for base class would be applied to derived classes.

Decorating base class property with `DependencyAttribute` is not allowed due to my project restrictions.

---

[Mirror of the question on Unity's codeplex site](http://unity.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=218749)

Comment: What you are looking for is called *auto-registration*, *scanning* or *convention-based registration*. Many DI Containers (like Castle Windsor and StructureMap) support this, but Unity does not. May I recommend a better DI Container?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid it is not possible to switch to another DI framework at this moment. Actually, I'm looking for smart BuildUp rather than automatic registration of all my descendants. Of course, auto-registration would let me achieve my goal, too. But taking inheritance into account would be more appropriate behavior I think.

Comment: Perhaps you will find this related question (and its answer) useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769056/does-ms-pnp-unity-scan-for-assemblies-like-structuremap

Comment: Thanks, @Mark. However, auto-registration is not what I need. I need  injections registered for ancestor to be applied to descendant. I don't want to register descendant at all. Furthermore, descendant could be registered with some specialized injections. And all the injections ("inherited" and "specialized") should be applied.

Answer (score 6):

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container
    .RegisterType<IDependency, Dependency1>()
    .RegisterTypes(
        AllClasses
            .FromAssemblies(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .Where(t => typeof(Base).IsAssignableFrom(t)),
        getInjectionMembers: _ => new[] { new InjectionProperty("Dependency") });
var d1 = container.Resolve<Derived1>();
```

Note: you need Unity 3 that supports [Registration by convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx#sec23).

Comment: I was dreaming of this in year 2010 :)