# Unity IoC: How to scan/resolve for plugins/types in a folder

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a folder c:\myplugins.  How  do I tell Unity to scan and register all the *.dll that is of type IMyPlugins.

Similar to how StructureMap has a scanning method where you can provider the folder location.

Comment: This question was already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769056 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595578/

Answer (score 2):

If you are aiming for a plugin type architecture, I would very much advise using [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) for that functionality in your application. This is exactly the kind of task MEF was developed for. There is also nothing to stop you from using MEF and Unity side by side. Unity for components known at compile time and MEF for pulling in runtime components.